# Constructing complex data type in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have Hive table with primitive data types like this:

```
CustomerName|City|Product1|RatingByMe|RatingByOthers|Product2|RatingByMe|RatingByOthers
```

I wish to convert it to complex data types with 2 separate lines for 2 products and having this schema:

```
CustomerName|City|Product1|struct[RatingByMe,RatingByOthers]
CustomerName|City|Product2|struct[RatingByMe,RatingByOthers]
```

How can achieve this in Hive? Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just use an `union` and a `named_struct`

```sql
select
    CustomerName,
    City,
    Product1,
    named_struct("RatingByMe", RatingByMe, "RatingByOthers", RatingByOthers) as rating
from your_table
union all
select
    CustomerName,
    City,
    Product2,
    named_struct("RatingByMe", RatingByMe, "RatingByOthers", RatingByOthers) as rating
from your_table
```